# CORBA + JAVA + dynamic client - invoke() method of Request object fails

Tags: java, dynamic, client, request, corba

I have a very simple IDL file:

```
module tests{

  interface test {
    boolean isEquals(in any num1, in any num2);
  };
};
```

After using `idlj`, I had written the whole application (divided into server / servant / client) and it works ok. My only problem right now is that when I try to rewrite the client, so it could use the dynamic invocation, the `ivoke()` method of the Requst object fails.

The code for the client:

```
ORB orb = ORB.init(args, null);

org.omg.CORBA.Object objRef = orb.resolve_initial_references("NameService");

NamingContext ncRef = NamingContextHelper.narrow(objRef);
NameComponent nc = new NameComponent("testDynamic", "");
NameComponent[] path = {nc};
//Object objectRef = ncRef.resolve(path);
test objectRef = testHelper.narrow(ncRef.resolve(path));

(...)

Any any1 = orb.create_any();
Any any2 = orb.create_any();

NVList arglist = orb.create_list(2);
any1.insert_char('c');
any2.insert_char('d');
NamedValue nvArg = arglist.add_value("any1", any1, org.omg.CORBA.ARG_IN.value);
NamedValue nvArg2 = arglist.add_value("any2", any2, org.omg.CORBA.ARG_IN.value);

// create return value
Any result = orb.create_any();
// insert dummy value
result.insert_boolean(false);
NamedValue resultVal = orb.create_named_value("result", result, 
    org.omg.CORBA.ARG_OUT.value);

// create request
Request req = objectRef._create_request(null, "isEquals", arglist, resultVal);
req.invoke();
```

Running the client leads to an error, with the `req.invoke()` beeing an suspect:

(the last line in the error log is `at server.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:75)`, which is the `req.invoke()` method)

```
Error: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 207  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.WrapperInputStream.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.read_value_kind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.read_value(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(Unknown Source)
    at tests.testPOA._invoke(testPOA.java:36)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 207  completed: No
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: ----------BEGIN server-side stack trace----------
org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL:   vmcid: SUN  minor code: 207  completed: No
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.logging.ORBUtilSystemException.endOfStream(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.BufferManagerReadStream.underflow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_1.grow(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_2.alignAndCheck(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.WrapperInputStream.read_long(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.read_value_kind(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.TypeCodeImpl.read_value(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_any(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream.read_any(Unknown Source)
    at tests.testPOA._invoke(testPOA.java:36)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatchToServant(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaServerRequestDispatcherImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequestRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleInput(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.RequestMessage_1_2.callback(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.handleRequest(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.transport.SocketOrChannelConnectionImpl.doWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.performWork(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.orbutil.threadpool.ThreadPoolImpl$WorkerThread.run(Unknown Source)

----------END server-side stack trace----------  vmcid: SUN  minor code: 207  completed: No
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.MessageBase.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.giopmsgheaders.ReplyMessage_1_2.getSystemException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaMessageMediatorImpl.getSystemExceptionReply(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.processResponse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientRequestDispatcherImpl.marshalingComplete(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.protocol.CorbaClientDelegateImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.RequestImpl.doInvocation(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.se.impl.corba.RequestImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at server.TestClient.main(TestClient.java:75)
```

May I ask for a little help?
Thank you.

Comment: Corba! wow. so you're the one.

Comment: @MeBigFatGuy - please tell this to my professor:)

Answer (score 1):

Could be an issue with the type of parameters, something related with marshaling. Strings must be allocated using CORBA::string_alloc (or java equivalent)